# Analytics gets hundreds of users, no hits and no way to filter

Tags: google-analytics

For the past week my GA has been getting random jumps of hundreds of 'active users' on my account, with 0 data to go with them. I get no new page hits, location data, events, or other data, just users. I took GA off of my web servers and after a few minutes I'm left hundreds of 'users' on the site with 0 orange bubbles on the map or info about them.

I attempted to set up a specific event that triggers when a user hits my site, and then filter the traffic by the event action in the GA settings, but this had no effect. What is going on here? How can I filter out this bad traffic? I have previously implemented bot prevention measures.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this question might be a much better fit for [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). There are some knowledgeable people there regarding this kind of thing. But if you do post it there, please remove it here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *View Settings* → *Bot Filtering* → and tick the box for **Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders**.